# including jquery ui dialog in 3.3.1

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, admin

I went into the wordpress 3.3.1 folders to see if and what had changed specifically re the jQuery-ui-dialog for enqueueing it.(I am using admin_init, after all it is in the admin area)
Reason for doing so was I could not use the class name to set the options on the dialog.
i found the js files were differently named from what is used in the enqueue docm / help I have found.
eg they are (in the wordpress\wp-includes\js\jquery\ui" directory) now, all postfixed with .min eg jquery.ui.core.min, jquery.ui.dialog.min etc.

Question then,...Does this mean the names used in enqueueing should be the same.?

eg   wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog-min'); 
where before it was 
     wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');

One folder back (in \js\jquery) the "jquery.js" is still named the same.

I suspect that the enqueueing results in the following function using .dialog to fail (else the class name has changed?)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog(
     {
         dialogClass   : 'wp-dialog',
         autoOpen: false,
         width: 400,
         resizable: false,
         modal: true,
         title: "One Popup"
     });
```

The .dialog class does not respond / do anything.
Even tried the 
   $Mydialog = ....approach  for setting it after init, but no luck there either

Any help would be greatly appreciated,..many days of frustration and trying everything has had no success.
Thx
Neal

Answer (score 0):

Codex still lists it as jquery-ui-dialog, so I guess thats correct.

Are you also enqueueing jquery and jquery-ui-core before you enqueue jquery-ui-dialog?